# chaining table rows and columns - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

I would like to know how I could code this in jquery using chaining?

```
var table = document.getElementById("deliver_alt_table");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
$(rows[0].children[1]).css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

This code works - but how could it be written in jquery using one row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#deliver_alt_table") // sorta like getElementById()
.find("tr") // sorta like getElementsByTagName()
.eq(0)  // sorta like how you did rows[0]
.children() // sorta like rows[0].children
.eq(1) // sorta like rows[0].children[1]
.css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: I wonder how this accepted answer compares to my solution performance-wise.

Comment: my guess is, probably not much considering all the same helper functions are called. in fact it may be slower because the selector string has to be broken up and parsed before jQuery can callit's helper functions. also, it's a little more difficult to understand. +1 though.

Comment: So, maybe getting slightly off-topic... Is it generally considered bad practice to have "long" selectors vs. using discrete JQuery functions?

Comment: @m-albert - actually my method is much faster. see: https://jsfiddle.net/9rbq968u/

Answer (score 2):

Something like...

```
$("#deliver_alt_table tr:first > *:eq(1)").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

**EDIT:** Changed "nth-of-type" to "eq"